# heroku gunicorn / Flask App Running Error

Tags: python, flask, heroku, gunicorn, application-error

I'm trying to push my first flask app to heroku but I couldn't figure out what the problem is. I have tried many times to find the problem by following the errors but I felt I was spinning.This app is working in local but not on heroku

I tried many different methods and I have manually corrected the requirements.txt versions to eliminate the version problems but I cannot figure out what is the current problem.

Here is the **heroku logs --tail** output:

```
$ heroku logs --tail
2021-03-27T17:31:01.216069+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-03-27T17:31:01.216070+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2021-03-27T17:31:01.216070+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-03-27T17:31:01.216070+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2021-03-27T17:31:01.216071+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-03-27T17:31:01.216071+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2021-03-27T17:31:01.216072+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-03-27T17:31:01.216072+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2021-03-27T17:31:01.216073+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2021-03-27T17:31:01.216073+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-03-27T17:31:01.216080+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
2021-03-27T17:31:01.216311+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:01 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-03-27T17:31:01.257899+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:01 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271113+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:01 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271116+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271116+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271117+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271117+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271118+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271118+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271119+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271119+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271120+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271120+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271120+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271121+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271121+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271122+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271122+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271123+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271123+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271123+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271124+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271124+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271199+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
2021-03-27T17:31:01.271576+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:01 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-03-27T17:31:01.395630+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:01 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-03-27T17:31:01.395757+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:01 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-03-27T17:31:01.525831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-03-27T17:31:01.610510+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2021-03-27T17:31:01.614922+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-27T17:31:03.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2021-03-27T17:31:09.148954+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2021-03-27T17:31:11.566273+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:11 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2021-03-27T17:31:11.566853+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:11 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:56319 (4)
2021-03-27T17:31:11.566948+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:11 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2021-03-27T17:31:11.571477+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:11 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577573+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:11 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577574+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577575+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577576+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577576+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577576+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577577+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577578+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577578+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577579+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577579+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577580+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577580+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577581+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577581+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577582+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577582+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577583+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577583+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577583+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577584+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577589+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
2021-03-27T17:31:11.577776+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:11 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2021-03-27T17:31:11.580125+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:11 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587148+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:11 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587149+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587150+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587151+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587151+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587152+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587152+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587152+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587153+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587154+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587154+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587154+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587155+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587155+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587155+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587156+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587156+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587156+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587157+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587160+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587161+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587165+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
2021-03-27T17:31:11.587315+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:11 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2021-03-27T17:31:11.720435+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:11 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-03-27T17:31:11.720548+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-03-27 17:31:11 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2021-03-27T17:31:11.788282+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2021-03-27T17:31:11.923225+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

and the procfile is:

```
web: gunicorn app:app
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

Project file structure is seen as:

```
E:.
├───flaskblog
│   ├───errors
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───main
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───posts
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───static
│   │   └───profile_pics
│   ├───templates
│   │   ├───.vscode
│   │   └───errors
│   ├───users
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   ├───venv
│   │   ├───Include
│   │   ├───Lib
│   │   │   └───site-packages
│   │   │       ├───certifi
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───certifi-2020.12.5.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───chardet
│   │   │       │   ├───cli
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───metadata
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───chardet-4.0.0.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───click
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───click-7.1.2.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───dns
│   │   │       │   ├───rdtypes
│   │   │       │   │   ├───ANY
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───CH
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───IN
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───dnspython-2.1.0.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───email_validator
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───email_validator-1.1.2.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───flask
│   │   │       │   ├───json
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───Flask-1.1.2.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───flask_sqlalchemy
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.4.4.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───flask_wtf
│   │   │       │   ├───recaptcha
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───Flask_WTF-0.14.3.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───idna
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───idna-2.10.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───itsdangerous
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───itsdangerous-1.1.0.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───jinja2
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───Jinja2-2.11.3.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───markupsafe
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───MarkupSafe-1.1.1.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───pip
│   │   │       │   ├───_internal
│   │   │       │   │   ├───cli
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───commands
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───distributions
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───index
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───models
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───network
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───operations
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───build
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───install
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───req
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───resolution
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───legacy
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───resolvelib
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───utils
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───vcs
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───_vendor
│   │   │       │   │   ├───cachecontrol
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───caches
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───certifi
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───chardet
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───cli
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───colorama
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───distlib
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───_backport
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───html5lib
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───filters
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───treeadapters
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───treebuilders
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───treewalkers
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───_trie
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───idna
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───msgpack
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───packaging
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───pep517
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───pkg_resources
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───progress
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───requests
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───resolvelib
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───compat
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───toml
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───urllib3
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───contrib
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   ├───_securetransport
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───packages
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   ├───backports
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   ├───ssl_match_hostname
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───util
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───webencodings
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───pip-20.2.3.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───pkg_resources
│   │   │       │   ├───extern
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───_vendor
│   │   │       │   │   ├───packaging
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───pytz
│   │   │       │   ├───zoneinfo
│   │   │       │   │   ├───Africa
│   │   │       │   │   ├───America
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───Argentina
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───Indiana
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───Kentucky
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───North_Dakota
│   │   │       │   │   ├───Antarctica
│   │   │       │   │   ├───Arctic
│   │   │       │   │   ├───Asia
│   │   │       │   │   ├───Atlantic
│   │   │       │   │   ├───Australia
│   │   │       │   │   ├───Brazil
│   │   │       │   │   ├───Canada
│   │   │       │   │   ├───Chile
│   │   │       │   │   ├───Etc
│   │   │       │   │   ├───Europe
│   │   │       │   │   ├───Indian
│   │   │       │   │   ├───Mexico
│   │   │       │   │   ├───Pacific
│   │   │       │   │   └───US
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───pytz-2021.1.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───requests
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───requests-2.25.1.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───setuptools
│   │   │       │   ├───command
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───extern
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───_distutils
│   │   │       │   │   ├───command
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───_vendor
│   │   │       │   │   ├───packaging
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───setuptools-49.2.1.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───sqlalchemy
│   │   │       │   ├───connectors
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───databases
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───dialects
│   │   │       │   │   ├───firebird
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───mssql
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───mysql
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───oracle
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───postgresql
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───sqlite
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───sybase
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───engine
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───event
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───ext
│   │   │       │   │   ├───declarative
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───orm
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───pool
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───sql
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───testing
│   │   │       │   │   ├───plugin
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───suite
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───util
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───SQLAlchemy-1.3.23.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───urllib3
│   │   │       │   ├───contrib
│   │   │       │   │   ├───_securetransport
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───packages
│   │   │       │   │   ├───backports
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───ssl_match_hostname
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───util
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───urllib3-1.26.3.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───werkzeug
│   │   │       │   ├───debug
│   │   │       │   │   ├───shared
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───middleware
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───wrappers
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───Werkzeug-1.0.1.dist-info
│   │   │       ├───wtforms
│   │   │       │   ├───csrf
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───ext
│   │   │       │   │   ├───appengine
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───csrf
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───dateutil
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───django
│   │   │       │   │   │   ├───templatetags
│   │   │       │   │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───i18n
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   ├───sqlalchemy
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───fields
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   ├───locale
│   │   │       │   │   ├───ar
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───bg
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───ca
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───cs_CZ
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───cy
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───de
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───de_CH
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───el
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───en
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───es
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───et
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───fa
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───fi
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───fr
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───he
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───hu
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───it
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───ja
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───ko
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───nb
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───nl
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───pl
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───pt
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───ru
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───sk
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───sv
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───tr
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───uk
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   ├───zh
│   │   │       │   │   │   └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   │   └───zh_TW
│   │   │       │   │       └───LC_MESSAGES
│   │   │       │   ├───widgets
│   │   │       │   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       │   └───__pycache__
│   │   │       ├───WTForms-2.3.3.dist-info
│   │   │       └───__pycache__
│   │   └───Scripts
│   └───__pycache__
└───__pycache__
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

PS: after long hours of searching and many tweaking of settings the solution was the change the name `app.py` to `main.py` then change procfile `web: gunicorn main:app`

I hope this help to who face the same problem with me.

Comment: Based on this I'm guessing your `Procfile` is incorrect: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`. Are you able to run locally via [`heroku local`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-local-processname)? Please [edit] your question to show us your `Procfile` and project directory structure.

Comment: please share procfile too

Comment: Thanks for updating. Unfortunately, your directory tree isn't as helpful as it could be. Please remove all the `__pycache__` directories, remove the `venv` directory, and add the _files_ in each of the directories. We need to understand your project structure.

Answer (score 0):

This is the error you should look at: `2021-03-27T17:31:11.587165+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'`

Probable reasons for this error:

1. `Procfile` not well declared

```py
# This is how it should be:

web: flask db upgrade; gunicorn tinker:app
```

The `Procfile` begins with a process name (in this case, it is a web application, so we will use `web`). After the colon, you will need to define the commands you need. Finally, you need to declare your server.

2. Similar names used for your application entry file and the *app* sub-folder. This is what I mean:

```py
project_folder
     | ----------app.py # entry file
     | ----------config.py
     | ----------app/
                   | ---------- __init__.py
                   | ---------- routes.py
                   | ---------- templates/
                   | ---------- static/
```

As seen in this structure, your application entry file is called `app.py`. If you are using a different structure, this file is where you run your code. Note that this name is the same as the *app* subfolder.

So, when you are declaring your web app in `Procfile`, what you should do is to first rename the entry file name in your application structure to something else such as `my_entry_file.py` . Then add it to the `Procfile`:

```
web: flask db upgrade; gunicorn my_entry_file:app
```

Comment: Please don't put `flask db upgrade` in your `web` process. There is no reason to run this every time your app starts and putting it here gives you no protection in case the upgrade fails. A [`release` process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/release-phase#specifying-release-phase-tasks) would be a better fit.

Comment: @Chris thank you for the suggestion. I will look into using `release`  since I have always used `flask db upgrade`. I appreciate the link too.